# How to display time in HH:MM format in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Am getting time from API as in the format 13:45:56 and i wanna display it as 13:45(HH:MM) . Can anyone help me? I tried to use Date pipe along with the binding tag, but it throws an error  as

```
 InvalidPipeArgument: '23:00:00' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

Comment: '13:45:56', that is in string format, right?

Comment: yes ,it is in string format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you guys for your valuable comments . Appreciating your efforts. I fixed it by using a pipe. it will be look bit complex, but really useful for applying in multiple queries.
Adding pipe query here with

### datepipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'datepipe' })
export class DateSet implements PipeTransform {
  transform(timeString: string ) {
    let time;
    time = timeString.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [timeString];
    if (time.length > 1) { // If time format correct
      time = time.slice (1);  // Remove full string match value
      time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; // Set AM/PM
      time[3] = ' ';
      time[4] = ' ';
      time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12; // Adjust hours
    }
    return time.join ('');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it in the following way as well:

```
<span class="dt-time">{{ entity.created_at | utcTimeConversion: utcOffset : "MMM DD YYYY"}}</span>
```

Here i am also taking into consideration the UTC offset alongside the format, this would ensure that the mobile device converts the time as per the timezone of the device..

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

HH  - Hour, 24-hour, leading zero   00 ... 23
h   - Hour, 12-hour 1 ... 12
hh  - Hour, 12-hour, leading zero   01 ... 12

m   - Minute    1 ... 59
mm  - Minute, leading zero  01 ... 59

So you can simply write HH:mm

> EX:  `<ion-datetime display-format="HH:mm"></ion-datetime>`

Comment: No it's not displaying. I just provided it, but it working as an input box <ion-datetime display-format="HH:mm" >{{bus.departureTime}} </ion-datetime >

Comment: Please check the stackblitz link provided in the answer section. Thank you ,appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's `DatePipe` expects a date according to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

> ....a Date object, a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch), or an ISO string.

So you need to convert your time from the API to one of these if you want to format it via Angular.

Btw, is it no option to just remove the second part of your time string which you get from the API?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-formatr) for your solution. This project might help you.